# Scroll down pages from top to bottom

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have multiple URLs which is open by python script. I have to scroll down all the web pages from top to bottom. I don't want to use hard coding for height of web page.

I am using below line to scroll down the web page:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

But Could not run form top to bottom.
Is there any way to do scroll from top to bottom for every web page I have opened?

Comment: what do you want to achieve by scrolling down? Usually selenium loads the complete webpage in 1 go with all javacripts and stuff..

Comment: The page contains data, information and details. Which I want to show in big screen

Comment: Is there any way to know status of last executed command :self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.SPACE). So we can handle dynamically it.

Comment: is it fine with below approach:

Comment: is it fine with below approach:
Calculate the page height: document.body.scrollHeight &
Calculate number of scrolling (How many times required to press space key Keys.SPACE)
Can we relate it ? How?

Answer (score 1):

try using `END` key, to reach bottom of a web page.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Reference:

1. http://www.pcworld.com/article/209766/Keyboard_Shortcut_Jump_to_the_Top_or_Bottom_of_Any_Web_Page.html

Comment: My requirement is navigating page in readable manner. So I could not use Keys.END because it kick to end point of page in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

`self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)`

If you have a footer or something on the bottom of the page, scroll to it

Comment: I have not footer in some of pages.